# Pickle memory error when saving 9GB dataframe

Tags: python, pickle

I am reading images from around 100 folder into dataframe with each folder having a row in the dataframe . After reading these images , I want to save them to pkl file . When I use

```
 pd.to_pickle(dataset,'.\\dataset.pkl')
```

Memory error is showing, I tried different methods like hdf5,parquest but still showing error . below is dataframe info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 60 entries, dev_01 to dev_09
Data columns (total 1 columns):
videos    60 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 9.7 GB


 videos_dataframe

folder_01   [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 34.0, 49.0, 60.0, ...
folder_010  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 66.0, 75.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0...
folder_011  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
folder_012  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
folder_013  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, 41.0, 58.0, 73.0, 81.0...
folder_014  [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 26.0, 48.0, ...
folder_015   [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 16.0, 30...
```

I splitted the dataframe into 10 parts :

```
splits=np.array_split(df, 10)
with open('split_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_out:  
pickle.dump(splits, pickle_out)
```

But still showing memory error :

```
          Traceback (most recent call last)
         <ipython-input-23-51fab4cebf2c> in <module> 
         3 with open('dev_split_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_out:
       ----> 4     pickle.dump(splits, pickle_out)

 MemoryError:
```

Comment: simply is to big the dataframe for you to have sved in pickle, is a bug related to it that anything more than 2gb would not be possible to save to .pkl so best approach for you is to split the dataframe in multiple smaller ones and save to pkl, than when reading them back just do a concatenation of the dataframes ...

Comment: @n1tk: In modern pickle protocol (4), the *protocol* should support arbitrarily huge pickles (no 2 GB limit). `pandas` uses the highest available protocol, but if this is Python 2 code, that would only be protocol 2. We need to know Python version and possibly OS (some OSes have trouble with large individual writes).

Comment: Memory Error happens when you try to load the whole dataset into your RAM and there is not enough memory . So instead of loading the whole dataset, you can load batch of data and then process it. You can also try keras image generator  function to load images from the folder, which is memory efficient.

Comment: @ShadowRanger than the OP need to provide more details of what python version uses and what version of pandas and pickle is used ... and than if is supported protocol 4 than should include when is saving to .pkl with latest protocol as: "DataFrame.to_pickle(path, compression='infer', protocol=4)" and with more details from https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format

Comment: Thanks very much for the replys , I'm using python 3 , windows 10 and pandad 0.23.4. I will try to split dataframe and use : DataFrame.to_pickle(path, compression='infer', protocol=4) , Thanks , I will post update if splitting works